# Mapping in multiple columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas, indexing, mapping

```
title_query = """SELECT ean, productTitle FROM `xxlhoreca-bi.PriceSearch_BackUp.XXL_Price_All`"""
title_df = client.query(title_query).to_dataframe()
final_result['productTitle'] = final_result['ean'].map(title_df.set_index('ean')['productTitle'])
```

I have a table with duplicate EANs (other columns are slightly different) and for some of them `productTitle` is null, I am putting `productTitle` for those do not have a title and have matching EAN.

However, now I have updated the data and I have multiple EANs + shops. And I want to match EAN+shop and then add missing titles.

Something like:

```
      ean | productTitle | shop 
----------+--------------+-------
      123 |  Table       |   FR
      123 |              |   FR
      123 |  Tisch       |   DE
      123 |              |   DE
```

I want output to be like:

```
      ean | productTitle | shop 
----------+--------------+-------
      123 |  Table       |   FR
      123 |  Table       |   FR
      123 |  Tisch       |   DE
      123 |  Table       |   DE
```

I have tried like:

```
title_query = """SELECT ean, shop, productTitle FROM `xxlhoreca-bi.PriceSearch_BackUp.XXL_Price_All`"""
title_df = client.query(title_query).to_dataframe()
final_result['productTitle'] = final_result['ean'].map(title_df.set_index('ean','shop')['productTitle'])
```

But getting an error:

```
pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Any helps would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
   title_df["ean"=="123"]["productTitle"] = "Table"
```

Comment: Cannot do in this way, because there are around 5000 rows.